# flask json output look like different when Apache/uWSGI or Werkzeug will be used

Tags: python, apache, flask, uwsgi, flask-restful

Json output look like different when Apache/uWSGI and Werkzeug will be used. 
Where's the trick?

see example:

Werkzeug:

```
curl -k -iL http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.6
Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2018 18:13:37 GMT

{
  "data": "Hello, Api!"
}
```

The same code powered by Apache/uWSGI:

```
curl -k  -iL https://flask.xxxxx.local/test/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2018 18:13:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 27

{"data":"Hello, Api!"}
```

i'am await for:

```
{
  "data": "Hello, Api!"
}
```

The piece of code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, render_template, g
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, fields, marshal
...
@app.route('/test/')
def get_resource():
   headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
   content = { 'data': 'Hello, Api'}
   return make_response(jsonify(content),200,headers)
...

Flask==1.0.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
uWSGI==2.0.17.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

thx

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear to me what you are asking, would you mind writing more about what you are trying to do and what your question is?

Comment: solved: app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference is the Flask config setting `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR`

This setting has default value `False` but will always be `True` when running in debug mode.

So when you run under uWsgi/Apache, the default setting of `False` is used, giving no indentation/newlines. When you run under the Werkzeug test server in debug mode, Flask sets the value to `True`.

To get indents and newlines under uwsgi, do the following in your wsgi script:

```
app = Flask(...)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True
```

See documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR

Also, you do not need the `make_response()` call. You can simply do:

```
@app.route('/test/')
def get_resource():
   content = { 'data': 'Hello, Api'}
   return jsonify(content)
```

... and Flask will set the correct content-type.